# +[UIView onBackgroundRequest:]: unrecognized selector sent to class

Tags: ios, swift

Deployment target: 8.4
Swift: 2.0

I have UIViewController class which has an *UITableView* and an *UIView* as it's `tableHeaderView`. UIViewController class has an UINotification listener, and the UIView which used as `tableHedearView` **dispatches** an UINotification.

My UIViewController class is fairly simple.

**StartViewController** (*UIViewController*):

```
class StartViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var tblContents: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // table header view
        let headerView = StartTableHeaderView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tblContents.bounds.width, self.view.frame.height*0.3))
        tblContents.tableHeaderView = headerView

        // adds notification listener
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "onBackgroundRequested:", name: "changeBackground", object: nil)
    }

    func onBackgroundRequested(notification:NSNotification)
    {
        let uiImagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        uiImagePicker.delegate = self
        uiImagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary

        self.presentViewController(uiImagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension StartViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
{
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

**StartTableHeaderView** (*UIView*):

```
class StartTableHeaderView: UIView
{
    ...

    @IBAction func onBackgroundRequest(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("changeBackground", object: nil)
    }
}
```

In runtime, whenever the method (*onBackgroundRequest*) fires upon a button tap in **StartTableHeaderView** and it dispatches the UINotification, I'm hitting with the following error:

> 2015-10-06 17:31:00.738 Elmo[1838:55864] +[UIView
>   onBackgroundRequest:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3272d90
>   2015-10-06 17:31:00.745 Elmo[1838:55864] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[UIView
>   onBackgroundRequest:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3272d90'

Comment: You need to `removeObserver` when the object deallocates

Comment: I have this in my class, though:
`deinit
    {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self);
    }`

Comment: In the exception it seems you're trying to call onBackgroundRequest UIView class method, and there's no such method in the code you've posted...

Comment: That is what I'm not sure - observer is added to `self` which is UIViewController, and I have `onBackgroundRequest` method there (as you can see in my source), then how it's trying to look the method in UIView!

Comment: There's no onBackgroundRequest method in your UIViewController. There's onBackgroundRequested method

Comment: Sorry for my earlier typo, but `onBackgroundRequested` is the method in my original source which is mentioned as selector and also present in same UIViewController class.

Comment: It's very confusing... What do you mean by "original source"? Can you please edit the question and put in the relevant source code, and the relevant exception? Also, it'd be great if you could specify where exactly it fails - it would be much easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the action on your button in class `StartTableHeaderView` that calls `onBackgroundRequest:` set up? Are you using Interface Builder or doing it in code?
If in code, can you post that?

I think you may not be posting the notification like you think. Put a breakpoint inside `StartTableHeaderView` `onBackgroundRequest:` and see if it is ever triggered.

The error is telling you that `onBackgroundRequest:` is not found, not `onBackgroundRequested:`.

Comment: Somehow the link between XIB and class file of `StartTableHeaderView`  were not working correctly. Although its managed to display without throwing an error but any IB connection to the class were turning fatal. I required to delete the XIB and class file as I couldn't found any probable breaking point. Its working now fine. Thanks Steve!